# Looks like most members are software folks?

Tags: discussion

Just an observation - most of the profiles I have looked at, mention they are software developers.

Is this because Stack Exchange is most used for programming (stack overflow, etc.)

Does this skew answers to one "type" of mind?

Should there be an outreach for other people from different walks of life?

Comment: ... "type" of mind ... very punny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do tend to skew that direction. SE is starting to branch out, but a lot of us still know about SE because we write software. (Also it gives us the advantage of being a t computers all day.). A lot of energy is going into our blog at the moment, and that will give us a good public face.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the accepted answer, however don't think that there is not a growing number of Theological Geeks on here.  I am a PHP/MySQL/Javascript/JQuery web programmer, who also happens to have two years of seminary under his belt including original languages.  I am also promoting the site to seminary professors and pastors I know.  I think that things are going to heat up here fairly soon with some non-software guys.

Comment: nice............